# Which Ocean did samudra manthan take place in?

Tags: samudra-manthan

Do we know where exactly did samudra manthan occur and  if it ever did go on ?

Comment: if it ever did go on ? --- what does this mean?

Answer (score 8):

It is known by the name **Kshir Sagar**, as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kshir_Sagar):

> In Hindu cosmology, the Ocean of milk (kṣīroda, kṣīrābdhi or Kṣīra
> Sāgara) is the fifth from the center of the seven oceans. It surrounds
> the continent known as Krauncha.[2](http://www.upsbdb.org/pdf/Souvenir2012/ch-21.pdf) According to Hindu mythology, the
> devas (gods) and asuras (demons) worked together for a millennium to
> churn the ocean and release Amrita the nectar of immortal life.[2](http://www.upsbdb.org/pdf/Souvenir2012/ch-21.pdf) It
> is spoken of in the Samudra manthana chapter of the Puranas, a body of
> ancient Hindu legends. It is also the place where Vishnu reclines over
> Shesha Naga, along with his consort Lakshmi.

Quoting from [Srimad Bhagavatam (8.6.22)](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/8/6/22-23/):

> > क्षिप्‍त्वा **क्षीरो**दधौ सर्वा वीरुत्तृणलतौषधी: ।
> > मन्थानं मन्दरं कृत्वा नेत्रं कृत्वा तु वासुकिम् ॥ २२ ॥
> >
> > सहायेन मया देवा निर्मन्थध्वमतन्द्रिता: ।
> > क्लेशभाजो भविष्यन्ति दैत्या यूयं फलग्रहा: ॥ २३ ॥
>
> Translation
>
> O demigods, **cast into the Ocean of Milk** all kinds of vegetables, grass, creepers and drugs. Then, with My help, making Mandara Mountain the churning rod and Vāsuki the rope for churning, churn the Ocean of Milk with undiverted attention. Thus the demons will be engaged in labor, but you, the demigods, will gain the actual result, the nectar produced from the ocean.

Here is an [article](http://www.upsbdb.org/pdf/Souvenir2012/ch-21.pdf) for info on Seven Oceans in Hindu Mythology

According to Sankhya philsophy, there is Purusha and Prakriti (Spirit and Matter) This Prakriti is the Ksheera Sagara.

From the union of Purusha and Prakriti, the golden womb called Hiranya-garbha is formed(Brahma). From this is born the universe.

Comment: do we know what is it called today or where is it?

Comment: Not really sure but some say it's the Milky Way galaxy!

Comment: Please add a reference to this?

Comment: @Just_Do_It I've just added reference from Bhagavata Purana to make citation more reliable than Wikipedia.